# Arrays of abstract type in julia in functions

Tags: julia

I try to understand typing in Julia and encounter the following problem with `Array`. I wrote a function `bloch_vector_2d(Array{Complex,2})`; the detailed implementation is irrelevant. When calling, here is the complaint:

```
julia> bloch_vector_2d(rhoA)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching bloch_vector_2d(::Array{Complex{Float64},2})
Closest candidates are:
  bloch_vector_2d(::Array{Complex,2}) at REPL[56]:2
  bloch_vector_2d(::StateAB) at REPL[54]:1
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[64]:1
```

The problem is that an array of parent type is not automatically a parent  of an array of child type.

```
julia> Complex{Float64} <: Complex
true

julia> Array{Complex{Float64},2} <: Array{Complex,2}
false
```

I think it would make sense to impose in julia that `Array{Complex{Float64},2} <: Array{Complex,2}`. Or what is the right way to implement this in Julia? Any helps or comments are appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue is discussed in detail in the Julia Manual [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#Parametric-Composite-Types).

Quoting the relevant part of it:

> In other words, in the parlance of type theory, Julia's type parameters are invariant, rather than being covariant (or even contravariant). This is for practical reasons: while any instance of `Point{Float64}` may conceptually be like an instance of `Point{Real}` as well, the two types have different representations in memory:
>
> - An instance of `Point{Float64}` can be represented compactly and efficiently as an immediate pair of 64-bit values;
> - An instance of `Point{Real}` must be able to hold any pair of instances of `Real`. Since objects that are instances of Real can be of arbitrary size and structure, in practice an instance of `Point{Real}` must be represented as a pair of pointers to individually allocated Real objects.

Now going back to your question how to write a method signature then you have:

```
julia> Array{Complex{Float64},2} <: Array{<:Complex,2}
true
```

Note the difference:

- `Array{<:Complex,2}` represents a union of all types that are 2D arrays whose eltype is a subtype of `Complex` (i.e. no array will have this exact type).
- `Array{Complex,2}` is a type that an array can have and this type means that you can store `Complex` values in it that can have mixed parameter.

Here is an example:

```
julia> x = Complex[im 1im;
                   1.0im Float16(1)im]
2×2 Array{Complex,2}:
   im         0+1im
 0.0+1.0im  0.0+1.0im

julia> typeof.(x)
2×2 Array{DataType,2}:
 Complex{Bool}     Complex{Int64}
 Complex{Float64}  Complex{Float16}
```

Also note that the notation `Array{<:Complex,2}` is the same as writing `Array{T,2} where T<:Complex` (or more compactly `Matrix{T} where T<:Complex`).

Answer (score 5):

This is more of a comment, but I can't hesitate posting it.  This question apprars so often.  I'll tell you why that phenomenon must arise.

A `Bag{Apple}` is a `Bag{Fruit}`, right? Because, when I have a `JuicePress{Fruit}`, I can give it a `Bag{Apple}` to make some juice, because `Apple`s are `Fruit`s.

But now we run into a problem: my fruit juice factory, in which I process different fruits, has a failure.  I order a new `JuicePress{Fruit}`.  Now, I unfortunately get delivered a replacement `JuicePress{Lemon}` -- but `Lemon`s are `Fruit`s, so surely a `JuicePress{Lemon}` is a `JuicePress{Fruit}`, right?

However, the next day, I feed apples to the new press, and the machine explodes.  I hope you see why: `JuicePress{Lemon}` is **not** a `JuicePress{Fruit}`.  On the contrary: a `JuicePress{Fruit}` is a `JuicePress{Lemon}` -- I can press lemons with a fruit-agnostic press!  They could have sent me a `JuicePress{Plant}`, though, since `Fruit`s are `Plant`s.

Now we can get more abstract.  The real reason is: function input arguments are *contravariant*, while function output arguments are *covariant* (in an idealized setting)<sup>2</sup>.  That is, when we have

```
f : A -> B
```

then I can pass in *supertypes of `A`*, and end up with *subtypes of `B`*.  Hence, when we fix the first argument, the induced function

```
(Tree -> Apple) <: (Tree -> Fruit)
```

whenever `Apple <: Fruit` -- this is the covariant case, it preserves the direction of `<:`.  But when we fix the second one,

```
(Fruit -> Juice) <: (Apple -> Juice)
```

whenever `Fruit >: Apple` -- this *inverts* the diretion of `<:`, and therefore is called ***contra**variant*.

This carries over to other parametric data types, since there, too, you usually have "output-like" parameters (as in the `Bag`), and "input-like" parameters (as with the `JuicePress`).  There can also be parameters that behave like neither (e.g., when they occur in both fashions) -- these are then called **invariant**.

There are now two ways in which languages with parametric types solve this problem.  The, in my opinion, more elegant one is to mark every parameter: no annotation means invariant, `+` means covariant, `-` means contravariant (this has technical reasons -- those parameters are said to occur in "positive" and "negative position").  So we had the `Bag[+T <: Fruit]`, or the `JuicePress[-T <: Fruit]` (should be Scala syntax, but I haven't tried it).  This makes subtyping more complicated, though.

The other route to go is what Julia does (and, BTW, Java): all types are invariant<sup>1</sup>, but you can specify upper and lower unions at the call site.  So you have to say

```
makejuice(::JoicePress{>:T}, ::Bag{<:T}) where {T}
```

And that's how we arrive at the other answers.

---

<sup>1</sup>*Except for tuples, but that's weird.*

<sup>2</sup>*This terminology comes from [category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor#Covariance_and_contravariance). The `Hom`-functor is contravariant in the first, and covariant in the second argument.  There's an intuitive realization of subtyping through the "forgetful" functor from the category `Typ` to the poset of `Typ`es under the `<:` relation.  And the CT terminology in turn comes from [tensors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_of_vectors).*

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand. The thing is that julia is functional oriented (aiming at manipulating arrows in categories like JuicePress and not only Bag). Is its design really motivated from category theory? Thanks for editing my question too!

Comment: No, not motivated. The terminology comes from there, and it fits a bigger picture, but the problem arises on its own in every system with parametric types and subtyping.

Comment: I think it might be less ambiguous to write `(Tree -> Apple) <: (Tree -> Fruit)`. It took me a minute to grok that line.

Answer (score 4):

While the "how it works" discussion has been done in the another answer, the best way to implement your method is the following:

```
function bloch_vector_2d(a::AbstractArray{Complex{T}}) where T<:Real
    sum(a) + 5*one(T)  # returning something to see how this is working
end
```

Now this will work like this:

```
julia> bloch_vector_2d(ones(Complex{Float64},4,3))
17.0 + 0.0im
```

Comment: or just `bloch_vector_2d(a::AbstractMatrix{<:Complex})` following the suggestion in my answer (I assume @chau wants to restrict the signature to matrices given the function name).